# Disable dragging nodes outside of area in cytoscape.js

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using `cytoscape.js`.

I have allowed the user to drag the nodes, but right now it is also possible to drag the node outside of the 'canvas'.

I have looked at the options at http://js.cytoscape.org/#core/initialisation but I don't know how to make sure the nodes cannot leave the visible area `<div id="cy"></div>`.

Answer (score 3):

Try the automove extension: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-automove

It lets you set rules for node position, like constraining within the current viewport or a specified region.

Comment: Is there anything in core library to avoid drag outside library.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is long time ago, but today I have the same problem and this is my solution, just move the node back in.

```
cy.on('mouseup', function (e) {
    let tg = e.target;
    if (tg.group != undefined && tg.group() == 'nodes') {
        let w = cy.width();
        let h = cy.height();
        if (tg.position().x > w) tg.position().x = w;
        if (tg.position().x < 0) tg.position().x = 0;
        if (tg.position().y > h) tg.position().y = h;
        if (tg.position().y < 0) tg.position().y = 0;
    }
})
```