# Cystoscape is out of canvas border

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, cytoscape.js

I'm traying to contain the objects inside of cytoscape canvas without moving outside of max width and height, but if i drag the objects inside of canvas , they go outside of canvas border:

[image]

Actually i'm not using the canvas from HTML5, instead im using the canvas from cytoscape.js plugin so this makes more complicated to fix it.
I already saw cystoscape documentation to see if there are any kind of option to make the borders fixed and make the content inside resposive,but didnt found anything.

I would like to kow if there any way to trick this.

my code test:

[cystoscape box test](https://codepen.io/pratykus/pen/yLYYaQN)

``

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 // document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

 $('#cyto').attr("title", "try clicking and dragging around the canvas and nodes");


 tippy('#cyto')

 cy = cytoscape({
     container: document.getElementById('cyto'),


     style: cytoscape.stylesheet()

         // style for the nodes
         .selector('node')
         .css({
             'width': 70,
             'height': 70,
             'content': 'data(id)',
             'text-align': 'center',
             'color': '#506874',
             'background-color': '#20b2aa',
             'font-family': 'Oswald',
             'shape': 'roundrectangle',
             'font-size': 20

         })

         // style for the connecting lines
         .selector('edge')
         .css({
             'width': .9,
             'height': 0.2,
             'curve-style': 'bezier',
             'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
             'target-arrow-color': '#F3A712',
             'line-color': '#F3A712',
             // 'line-color': '#C40E0E',

         })
         .selector(':selected')
         .css({
             'background-color': '#428bca',
             'line-color': '#C40E0E',
             'target-arrow-color': '#C40E0E',
             'source-arrow-color': '#C40E0E'
         })
         .selector('.faded')
         .css({
             'opacity': 1,
             'text-opacity': 0
         }),

     elements: [
         {
             group: 'nodes',
             data: {
                 id: 'WORDS'
             }
      }, {
             group: 'nodes',
             data: {
                 id: 'REALITY'
             }
      },
         {
             group: 'nodes',
             data: {
                 id: 'THE WORLD'
             }
      },

         {
             group: 'nodes',
             data: {
                 id: 'PEOPLE'
             }
      },

         {
             group: 'nodes',
             data: {
                 id: 'ME'
             }
      },
         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge1',
                 source: 'PEOPLE',
                 target: 'WORDS'
             }
      },

         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge2',
                 source: 'PEOPLE',
                 target: 'REALITY'
             }
      },
         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge3',
                 source: 'ME',
                 target: 'WORDS'
             }
      },
         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge4',
                 source: 'WORDS',
                 target: 'THE WORLD'
             }
      },
         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge',
                 source: 'THE WORLD',
                 target: 'ME'
             }
      },
         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge6',
                 source: 'PEOPLE',
                 target: 'THE WORLD'
             }
      },
         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge7',
                 source: 'ME',
                 target: 'THE WORLD'
             }
      },

         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge9',
                 source: 'WORDS',
                 target: 'REALITY'
             }
      },
         {
             group: 'edges',
             data: {
                 id: 'edge5',
                 source: 'REALITY',
                 target: 'ME'
             }
      }
    ],
 }); // end cytoscape
 }, false);
```

``

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to prevent nodes from leaving the cytoscape.js border on drag?

Comment: @StephanT.yes, thats my issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable dragging nodes outside of area in cytoscape.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280268/disable-dragging-nodes-outside-of-area-in-cytoscape-js)

Comment: @StephanT.perhaps could work , but first i need to know how this extension works.

Answer (score 2):

Just like with any canvas object, you need to "listen" to the drag event and take action based on the position.

The code below is a push in the right direction, I'm just showing the position of the element as it is dragged, next you need to set your area boundaries and prevent the element from moving outside

```js
tippy("#cyto");

cy = cytoscape({
  container: document.getElementById("cyto"),

  style: cytoscape
    .stylesheet()
    .selector("node")
    .css({content: "data(id)"}),

  elements: [
    {data: { id: "WORDS" }},
    {data: { id: "REALITY" }}
  ]
});

cy.on('drag', 'node', function (evt) {
  var node = evt.target;
  var point = node.point();
  
  console.log(node.id() + " " + point.x + " " + point.y);
  if (point.y < 10)
    node.style({ 'background-color': 'red' });
  else
    node.style({ 'background-color': 'blue' });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  border: 2px blue solid;
  height: 160px;
  width: 400px;
}

#cyto {
  grid-row: 2/ span 1;
  grid-column: 1/ span 6;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@2.0.8/dist/tippy.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cytoscape/3.14.1/cytoscape.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div id="cyto">
  </div>
</div>
```

You could use the https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-automove but I strongly recommend you to understand this clearly before you start using extensions

Comment: thanks for suggestions , i will see if i can match the borders positions with node xy coordinates.

Comment: I added an if statement to my code changing the color of the node when the `y` is less than 10

Comment: it could work for each single node, but i would like to know if is possible to get the position of hole elements list of nodes because is also possible to drag the hole list instead : https://codepen.io/pratykus/pen/yLYYaQN

Comment: there must be an event for that too... check the documentation: https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.on  https://js.cytoscape.org/#eles.on